# Create Multiple volumes in one go aws cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, storage

I want to create multiple volumes via single Cloudformation template, While searching for the loops in cloudformation i found its not available.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this in CLoudformation.

This working `template` to create Single volume.

**Working template:**

```
---
Description: "Create FSx for ONTAP Filesystem"
Resources:
  AWSDemoVolume:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::Volume"
    Properties:
      Name: AWSBackupDemovol001
      OntapConfiguration:
        JunctionPath: /AWSBackupDemovol001
        SizeInMegabytes: 150
        StorageEfficiencyEnabled: true
        StorageVirtualMachineId: "svm-04c2e2830ff42097e"
        TieringPolicy:
          CoolingPeriod: 2
          Name: AUTO          
      VolumeType: "ONTAP"
      Tags:
        - Key: "Bacup_Tag"
          Value: "backup"
        - Key: "Created_By"
          Value: "Cloud Micron"
...
```

While looking at various suggestion i tried Bleow but not working.

```
---
Description: >
  This template Deploys Multiple FsxN Volume from an existing Storage Virtual Machines(SVM).
Resources:
  AWSDemoVolume:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::Volume"
    Properties:
      Name: AWSDemovol001"%d"
      OntapConfiguration:
        JunctionPath: /AWSDemovol00"%d"
        SizeInMegabytes: 150
        StorageEfficiencyEnabled: true
        StorageVirtualMachineId: "svm-08c5e3580ff41023e"
    Count: 3
      VolumeType: "ONTAP"
      Tags:
        - Key: "Bacup_Tag"
          Value: "backup"
        - Key: "Created_By"
          Value: "Cloud Micron"
...
```

I want to create 3 more volumes names like `AWSDemovol001 AWSDemovol002 and AWSDemovol003`.

please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There are no loops in CloudFormation. The only way to achieve what you want is through [macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

So you have to develop your own macro or a custom resource in the form of a **lambda function** to perform the iterative creation of multiple volumes.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, for the great guidance as always,  do you have an example which i can refer to my use case above.